# How to preserve a datepicker value?

Tags: c#, razor, web-applications, razor-pages

So i have a daterpicker. I was asked to make the datepicker remember the date it was given when you were using it to search for a date.
The codes:

```
[BindProperty, DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="TestClick">
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" value="yyyy-mm-dd" />
        <button>Search</button>
        <br />

    </form>
```

from a .cshtml file

```
public void OnPostTestClick()
        {
            String testDate = Request.Form["Date"];
            Debug.WriteLine("Testclick verdi2 = " + testDate);
            filterdato = testDate;
            ListData();
        }
```

from .cshtml.cs file

I was told where the code should probably be, but I don't know how to do it. IS there anyone that could help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an input tag helper for rendering the date input. The following is all you need:

```
<input asp-for="Date" />
```

See more about working with dates and times in Razor Pages forms on my site: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/dates-and-times

Also, you don't need to reference `Request.Form`. You can rely on Model binding to bind the posted value to your Date property:

```
public void OnPostTestClick()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Testclick verdi2 = " + Date);
    filterdato = testDate;
    ListData();
}
```

Here's more about model binding: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding